# site admin for subscribers

Tags: admin, subscription

I want a very basic page for my subscribers to change their passwords and profile.

No Wordpress news etc.

Is is possible to strip the admin section of subscribers and leave the absolutely bare minimals?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, try Adminimize: http://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/

Comment: Subscribers already have a very limited admin section. What else are wanting to remove?